# Missing TestSummeries.plist file in DerivedData

Tags: testing, xcode11, ios13

I am running unit tests on iOS 13.0 device by using xcode 11 beta. After the test execution it should generate a testsummeries.plist file inside

/Users/YourUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX/Logs/Test/xxx.xcresult

for the corresponding test case.

But it is only generating data folder and info.plist file inside .xcresult.

So i am not able get my report of the test cases that i have executed

In Xcode 10 it was working properly and with each test run i was able to see my test status in testsummeries.plist file inside DerivedData folder.

1 - Do i need to configure something in xcode11 beta so that it will generate the same?

2 - Is there any other location where i can get the test case report?enter image description here

Actual content:

[image: Actual]

Expected content:

[image: Expected]

Comment: Is there a particular tool you're hoping to use the TestSummaries.plist with?  What do you need it for?  As @ablarg mentioned, Apple changed the format & so what you need to do now varies depending on what you do with that plist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple has changed the format of testResultBundles in Xcode 11.0.
The new format is a bundle.xcresult. You can set a expected location for this to be output by using -resultBundlePath ResultBundle.xcresult.

You can then extract the results in a JSON format that you can query using the new tool:

`$ xcrun xcresulttool get --path ResultBundle.xcresult --format json`

You can read find out more about the format and tools to support it in this presentation:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/413

Slide 155 of the associated PDF appears to have the information you require:

[image]

some caveats:

- Only available in Xcode 11 and later
- the `xcresulttool` will be specific to the Xcode generating the results