# How to extract details from xcresult file in XCUITest (from Xcode 11)?

Tags: xctest, extract, xcuitest

I want to parse and get all the details related to my UI tests from **xcresult** file. Before Xcode 11, I can achieve this by reading the **TestSummaries.plist** file. But Apple has changed the [xcresult format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471506/missing-testsummeries-plist-file-in-deriveddata) from Xcode 11.

I found [this](https://www.chargepoint.com/engineering/xcparse/) on google. But seems like it can only extract the screenshots from the **xcresult** bundle. I want to extract all details like, start/end times, action/activities times, code coverage details and logs etc.

Apple itself provide **xcresulttool** command line tool to see the xcresults in a human readable format. But it also does not gives all the needed information.

I saw about [XCTestObservation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestobservation) & [XCTestRun](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestrun) to build my own test observer but can't find any workable sample in the internet. Am I missing something? Did anyone throw some help on this?

Answer (score 6):

[XCTestHTMLReport](https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/XCTestHTMLReport) has helped me to obtain beautiful HTML report with screenshots.